# Understanding the proof of Fano's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

If we have the markov triple

\begin{align*}
X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow \hat X
\end{align*}

Where $X$ is a random variable, $Y$ a random variable correlated to $X$ and $\hat X$ is our *estimate* of $X$.

Using Fano's inequality we are able to bound the error $P_e = \mathbb{P}[\hat X \neq X ]$ we make with respect to the conditional entropy $H(X| \hat X)$. The result wil be:

\begin{align*}
P_e \ge \frac{H(X\mid Y) - 1}{log |\chi|}
\end{align*}

However, a part of the proof includes to show that

\begin{align*}
H(E,X \mid \hat X) &= H(X\mid \hat X) + \underbrace{H(E \mid X, \hat X)}_{= 0} \\
&= H(E\mid \hat X) + H(X \mid E, \hat X)
\end{align*}

Where $E$ is a RV indicating whether $X$ is equal to $\hat X$

\begin{align*}
E = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } X \neq \hat X \\ 0 & \text{if } X = \hat X \end{cases}
\end{align*}

If we look at $H(E,X \mid \hat X)$ we already see that:

\begin{align*}
H(X\mid \hat X) = H(E\mid \hat X) + H(X \mid E, \hat X)
\end{align*}

And since $H(E\mid X) \leq H(E) = H(P_e)$ we immediately see that

\begin{align*}
H(X\mid \hat X) \leq H(P_e) + H(X \mid E, \hat X)
\end{align*}

Here comes the part I do not quite understand about $H(X \mid E, \hat X)$. In the textbook it's stated that

\begin{align*}
H(X\mid E, \hat X) &= \mathbb{P}[E=0]H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) + \mathbb{P}[E=1]H(X\mid \hat X, E = 1) \\
&\leq (1 - P_e) \cdot 0 + P_e \log_2 |\chi |
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{align*}
H(P_e) + P_e \log |\chi | \geq H(X\mid \hat X) \geq H(X \mid Y)
\end{align*}

where the last inequality follows from the data-processing inequality.

---

What I am not getting is why $H(X\mid E, \hat X)$ can be written as

\begin{align*}
H(X\mid E, \hat X) &= \mathbb{P}[E=0]H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) + \mathbb{P}[E=1]H(X\mid \hat X, E = 1)
\end{align*}

and also why this is limitted by $P_e \log_2 |\chi|$. The equation tells me that $H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) = 0$ and my textbook argues that

> "*Since given $E = 0$, we have $X = \hat X$.*"

but still I don't see how this is equal to $0$.

---

Further, I've stated $H(E \mid X, \hat X)= 0$ and this is argued because $E$ is a function of $X$ and $\hat X$. But why is $H(X \mid E, \hat X)\neq 0$?

Intuitively I'd say $H(E \mid X, \hat X)= 0$ because once I know $X$ and $\hat X$ I also know $E$, hence there is no more information to be added. However, this is not the same for $H(X \mid E, \hat X)$ - but how can I argue this?

Answer (score 2):

I thought two issues may confuse you, 1) one is the expansion of the conditional entropy, 2) the other is what it means to say "distribution $E$ is a function of $X$ and $\hat X$".

---

To illustrate the definition of Conditional Entropy in detail, I'd like to show you a simple and concrete example. On page 30 of the *Elements of Information Theory* there is an example: 
[image]
In the calculation bellow the author calculates $H(X|Y)$ as the following:

> $H(X|Y)=\frac{3}{4}H(X|Y=1)+\frac{1}{4}H(X|Y=2)$

That's to say: $H(X|Y)=Pr(Y=1)H(X|Y=1)+Pr(Y=2)H(X|Y=2)$

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy) you will check the definition of the conditional entropy:

> $H(Y|X)=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(x)H(Y|X=x) $

The same apllies to this equation which you didn't get:

> \begin{align*}
> H(X\mid E, \hat X) &= \mathbb{P}[E=0]H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) + \mathbb{P}[E=1]H(X\mid \hat X, E = 1)
> \end{align*}

---

Secondly, the saying that "distribution $E$ is a function of $X$ and $\hat X$" refers to this: 
[image]
That's what E is in the proof. Obviously $E$ is a function of $X$ and $\hat X$. Given any fixed $X$ and $\hat X$ the $E$ is determined, hence the conditional entropy $H(E|X,\hat X)$ is 0.

Given that $E=0$ which means $X=\hat X$(according to the difinition of $E$ above), the conditional entropy,

\begin{align*}
H(X, |\hat X, E=0)=H(X, \hat X|E=0)-H(\hat X|E=0)\overset{X=\hat X}{=}H(X) - H(X)=0 
\end{align*}

However for $H(X \mid E=1, \hat X)$ it is, 
\begin{align*}
H(X \mid E=1, \hat X)=H(X, \hat X|E=1)-H(\hat X|E=1)\overset{X\neq\hat X}=H(X, \hat X) - H(\hat X) \neq 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

> What I am not getting is why $H(X\mid E, \hat X)$ can be written as
>   \begin{align*}
> H(X\mid E, \hat X) &= \mathbb{P}[E=0]H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) + \mathbb{P}[E=1]H(X\mid \hat X, E = 1)
> \end{align*}

It's a property (sometimes a definition) of conditional entropy: the conditional entropy equals the expected value of the entropy conditioned on particular values of the conditioning variable:

$$H( X | Y) = \sum_y P(Y=y) H(X | Y=y)$$

The formula above just applies this to the random variable $E$ (it takes two values, $0$ and $1$).

---

$$H(X \mid \hat X, E = 0) = 0$$

This can be seen thus: $E=0$ implies that there was no error in the estimation; hence, knowing this, *and* knowing the estimated value $\hat X$, we just know the value of $X$ ($X = \hat X$), so we have no incertitude about $X$, hence the entrop is zero.

I'm not sure if this answers all your doubts.